# DropDown List Ember On Pressing Cancel button should roll back

Tags: ember.js, dropdown

So I have a dropdown list and on action it make a secondary dialog where it have two button confirm and cancel On cancel I want the old ember dropdown to come .Is there any way to achieve .I tried by setting the current active one as false and the old one as true but it's not working.

in a computed function I am making a object of dropdown and then putting them in a array and returning that

Comment: Can you please share some code? Especially the component, which renders the dropdown list and the secondary dialog, would be helpful.

Comment: Made it working first using foreach made active property as false for all the cases.Then iterated again and if  it i get the old values then by using setProperties to set the value as true.Worked like a charm Thank you